# lateinit property binding has not been initialized

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I know that there are similar questions to this, but I just cant find something that is similar, I've been studying new things to learn, and while converting kotlin synthetics to `viewvbinding` mode, I've encountered this error

> ```
> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property binding has not been initialized
>         at com.codepalace.chatbot.ui.MessagingAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MessagingAdapter.kt:60)
>         at com.codepalace.chatbot.ui.MessagingAdapter.onBindViewHolder(MessagingAdapter.kt:17)
> ```

It says that I have to initialize the binding, but I dont know where to put it.

This is the code.

```
class MessagingAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagingAdapter.MessageViewHolder>() {

var messagesList = mutableListOf<Message>()
private lateinit var binding: MessageItemBinding


inner class MessageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {

            //Remove message on the item clicked
            messagesList.removeAt(adapterPosition)
            notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessageViewHolder {

    return MessageViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.message_item, parent, false)
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return messagesList.size
}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentMessage = messagesList[position]


    when (currentMessage.id) {
        SEND_ID -> {
            holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_message).apply {
                binding.tvMessage.text = currentMessage.message
                visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_bot_message).visibility = View.GONE
        }
        RECEIVE_ID -> {
            holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_bot_message).apply {
                binding.tvBotMessage.text = currentMessage.message
                visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            holder.itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tv_message).visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}

fun insertMessage(message: Message) {
    this.messagesList.add(message)
    notifyItemInserted(messagesList.size)
}
```

Comment: Why You have `MessageItemBinding` in the adapter class?  I think it should be placed in the `ViewHolder` class so in Your case in `MessageViewHolder`

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I'm still new so I don't really understand much on where to put it.

Comment: Okay, I can try to make a short example and show how I make RecyclerView adapters

Comment: Thank you so much, but in order to use the id from the xml file, I have to use MessageItemBinding, if I try to change it, it errors out as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `private lateinit var binding: MessageItemBinding`

You didn't initialize the `binding` object, as you defined it as lateinit, then you should define it.

This is typically in `onCreateViewHolder`

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrackedActivityHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<MessageItemBinding>(inflater, R.layout.message_item, parent, false)
    return MessageViewHolder(
        binding
    )
}
```

**UPDATE**

You need to accept `MessageItemBinding` type instead of `View` in the `MessageViewHolder` constructor, and use `itemView.root` to get the root view of the list item.

```
inner class MessageViewHolder(itemView: MessageItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView.root) {
    init {
        itemView.root.setOnClickListener {

            //Remove message on the item clicked
            messagesList.removeAt(adapterPosition)
            notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error on MessageItemBinding that the argument is not within its bounds

Comment: Hi @JeffreyKurdtDreo please check UPDATE section in answer

Comment: <MessageItemBinding> still has an error,  argument is not within its bounds.

Comment: setOnClickListener also errors out, it says unresolved reference

Comment: Is there anyway you can try to edit the code? I just really need help

Comment: @JeffreyKurdtDreo Can you try this `binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.message_item, parent, false)` or `binding = MessageItemBinding.inflate(inflater)`

Comment: It fixed the error, but setOnCLickListener shows unresolved reference

Comment: When I try to remove it the others just error out

Comment: it showed expecting an element and unresolved reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233206/discussion-between-zain-and-jeffrey-kurdt-dreo).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why You get this error is that `MessageItemBinding` should not be in Adapter but in ViewHolder class. You can make RecyclerView like this:

```kotlin
object MessageDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Message>()
{
    override fun areItemsTheSame(
        oldItem: Message,
        newItem: Message
    ): Boolean =
            oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: Message,
        newItem: Message
    ): Boolean =
            oldItem == newItem
}
```

*I assume that `Message` is a data class. You have to create this `MessageDiffCallback` and override these 2 methods in a similar way that I did it.*

Now Create `ViewHolder` class:

```kotlin
class MessageViewHolder private constructor(
    private val binding: MessageItemBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
{
    companion object
    {
        fun create(parent: ViewGroup): MessageViewHolder 
        {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = MessageItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return MessageViewHolder(
                binding
            )
        }
    }

    fun bind(
        message: Messaage
    )
    {
        // Here You can do everything. 
        // You pass the message and based on this You can set up a view and use binding
    }
}
```

And now Adapter class

```kotlin
class MessageAdapter : ListAdapter<Message, MessageViewHolder>(MessageDiffCallback)
{
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MessageViewHolder =
            MessageViewHolder.create(parent)


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) =
            holder.bind(
                message = getItem(position),
            )
}
```

Now You should have a working adapter. To put data in it use `messageAdapter.submitList(messages)` in Your Fragment/Activity

---

*Maybe not the best answer because it changes Your code and uses a little different logic but it should work better. You can check [google sample code here](https://github.com/udacity/andfun-kotlin-sleep-tracker-with-recyclerview/blob/Step.14-Solution-Add-Header-to-GridLayout/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/sleeptracker/SleepNightAdapter.kt) or take [codelab here](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012/lessons/ee5a525f-0ba3-4d25-ba29-1fa1d6c567b8/concepts/8d0a8eb2-251e-4682-a105-da17fbec8ccd). It is free after signing up*